# Identify a specific dynamically generated TextView in order to setText

Tags: android, android-layout, onactivityresult

I have a function that generates a specific number of TextViews dynamically.

```
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    public TextView textViewGenerate(final Activity activity, String tag, Integer id) {

        tv = new TextView(activity);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
        gd.setCornerRadius(4);
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF757575);

        tv.setBackground(gd);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1.0f
        );

        tv.setPadding(7, 9, 0, 0);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        tv.setTextSize(22);

        tv.setTag(tag);
        tv.setId(id);
        tv.setHint("Enter Module Serial Number");

        //Click to launch camera
        tv.setClickable(true);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(ct, MctCameraActivity.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MctCameraActivity.class);
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                //ct.startActivity(intent);
                //ToDo: finish receiving the data from the activityForResult
            }
        });

        lp.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        lp.setMarginStart(10);
        lp.setMarginEnd(10);

        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return tv;
    }

}
```

The onClick launches another activity that loads the camera in order to capture barcode data. In the main activity I create the TextViews with

```
        final LayoutElements le = new LayoutElements();
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mctScanPageMain);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            mainLayout.addView(le.textViewGenerate(this, "NewID" + i, i));
        }
```

The onActivityResult returns the value from the camera activity but the issue is that it sets every generated TextView to have the same barcode number (the barcode number is returned as a string). How can I modify this so that only the text of the selected TextView gets changed in the onActivityResult?

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String returnResult = data.getStringExtra("result");

            for (int i=0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                TextView tv = (TextView) mainLayout.findViewWithTag("NewID"+i);
                if(tv == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    tv.setText(returnResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click listener of TextView you can change:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MctCameraActivity.class);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MctCameraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("text_view_tag", tag);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And then sent it back in result of `MctCameraActivity`, so you can use it in `onActivityResult` with `getStringExtra`. This way you will know tag of TextView which started activity.

Alternatively you can use `requestCode` that you pass to `startActivityForResult` to differentiate between text views. For example pass request code 1 for text view 1, request code 2 for text view 2 etc and use this `requestCode` in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on your last part. In my onActivityResult im using getStringExtra to send back the value (String) of the barcode (String returnResult = data.getStringExtra("result");) Do i add another another getStringExtra and set it to ("text_view_tag") and set the findViewWithTag to be that value? TextView tv = (TextView) mainLayout.findViewWithTag("text_view_tag");

Comment: Yes, you can just forward what you've get in intent before finishing with `setResult` in `MctCameraActivity` with something like `intent.putExtra("text_view_tag",getIntent().getStringExtra("text_view_tag")`. Then in `onActivityResult` find it with `mainLayout.findViewWithTag(data.getStringExtra("text_view_tag"))`.

Comment: I've added also alternative solution with using `requestCode` - value in `onActivityResult` going to be the same that you passed with `startActivityForResult` (you used 1 for all text views in your example). Maybe this approach you will like more.